# As3 AddChild() in a Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Im in as3 and Im trying to add a MovieClip inside of a Class I don't get any errors but my image does not show up.

This is my Class Code, my MovieClip is called woopa1

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import woopa1;

    public class koopa extends woopa1
    {
        public function koopa()      
        {
            trace(woopa1);
            var woopa:woopa1 = new woopa1();
            addChild(woopa);
            woopa.x=100;
            woopa.y=100;
            woopa.height = 60;
            woopa.width = 38;
        }
    }
}
```

It traces [Class woopa1]
this is my Code in the frame calling the class

```
function onenterEnemy(event:Event):void
{
   var enemy:koopa = new koopa();
}
```

Why doesn't my image show up?

Answer (score 3):

Have you added your `enemy` instance to the display list?

```
var enemy:koopa = new koopa(); 
addChild(enemy);
```

Also since you create an instance of your `woopa1` class and add it to `koopa`, your `koopa` class should probably extend `MovieClip` or `Sprite` instead of your `woopa1` class.

On a separate note, you may also want to name your classes with names that start with an uppercase character. So `koopa` should be `Koopa` and `woopa1` should be `Woopa1`.